# Which boolean law is this?

Tags: math, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-algebra

F = XYZ + XYZ' + XY'Z + X'YZ

= (XYZ + XYZ + XYZ) + XYZ' + XY'Z + X'YZ (i don't know what law was used to get this)

I was given some guidance on a question that has been troubling me, but would like to not make this mistake in future. can anyone tell me what law that is above?

Comment: off topic for stackoverflow , try maths stack

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics (Boolean algebra), not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to answer your later but to draw your attention toward the ["Idempotent Law"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) :-

For any boolean variable a,

```
a + a = a (Idempotent Law)
```

Next, now the answer to your question. This solution is nothing but an approach to simplify the minterms.

```
F = XYZ + XYZ' + XY'Z + X'YZ

  = (XYZ + XYZ + XYZ) + XYZ' + XY'Z + X'YZ 

  = (XYZ + XYZ') + (XYZ + XY'Z) + (XYZ + X'YZ)

  = XY(Z+Z') + XZ(Y+Y') + YZ(X+X')

  = XY + XZ + YZ.    (Since,  a + a' = 1 ,as per the Complement law)
```

So simple and this is it to solve this problem...

Answer (score 1):

This should be simple ....

Suppose we have `F=X` then we can write it as `F=X+X`.

This comes under [Indempotent Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Other_examples) `A+A=A`